# Comparing two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where I would like to verify that column A is greater than column B (row wise). I am doing something like

```
tmp=df['B']-df['A']
if(any( [ v for v in tmp if v > 0])):
   ....
```

I was wondering if there was better(concise) way of doing it  or if pandas dataframe had any such built in routines to accomplish this

Comment: are you just varifying that all values in column A are greater than from coulmn B respectively? if its valid to all respective values it will return True else False?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [3, 1, 1]})

temp = df['B'] - df['A']

print(temp)

0    2
1   -1
2   -2
```

Now you can create a Boolean series using `temp > 0`:

```
print(temp > 0)

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

This boolean series can be fed to `any` and therefore you can use:

```
if any(temp > 0):
    print('juhu!')
```

Or simply (which avoids `temp`):

```
if any(df['B'] > df['A']):
    print('juhu')
```

using the same logic of creating a Boolean series first:

```
print(df['B'] > df['A'])

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

df['B']>df['A'] will be pandas series in boolean datatype.

```
 >>> (df['B']>df['A']).dtype
      dtype('bool')
```

For example

```
>>> df['B']>df['A']
   0     True
   1    False
   2    False
   3     True
   4     True
   dtype: bool
```

any() function returns True if any of the item in an iterable is true

```
>>> if any(df['B']>df['A']):
...     print(True)
... 
     True
```

Comment: "you can try"?? could you please explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to check if any df[‘B'] > df[‘A’] then do something.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [2, 0, 6, 3]})
if np.where(df['B'] > df['A'], 1, 0).sum():
    print('do something')
```